# Javascript: How to write and call a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I need to call a function to post an account ID before I could retrieve an account for the user. In that function I need to check if the retrieved accounts has already exists on user's side, if exists, increase the query ID and rerun the function until the retrieved account is new to the user.

Since the function will call itself, so I guess what I'm doing is writing my first recursive function in my life.

I've tried:

```
<script>
    function updateAcc(maxVal) {

        $.post("accountUpdate.php", {maxVal:maxVal}, function(result){
            // get the retrieved account ID
            var result=$(result);
            pa.replaceWith(result);
            var resultid=result.attr("data-topic-id");
            var testlength=$('*[data-topic-id="'+resultid+'"]').length;
            // check if retrived account already exists on user's page
            // if exists alraedy, increase the query ID, run the function again, retrieved new account ID,until there's no same accounts on users' side
            if(testlength>1) {
                maxVal++;
                updateAcc();
            }

            // alert(resultid);
        })
    }
    // envoke the function
    updateAcc(maxVal)
</script>
```

Comment: and ...... what is not working?

Comment: When you call it recursively, you still need to pass the `maxVal` parameter.

Comment: for function call  ->  updateAcc();  need parameter maxVal

Comment: a better solution will be to drop the recursive and do some query manipulation `not in array()` the array you are bulding from the topics ids of the user

Comment: A recursive function is one which calls itself and *ultimately ends*. If it does not end then its better be called an infinite loop. So you should decide if you really need it.

Comment: This isn't "real" recursion, it's kind of pseudo-recursion, because your function *doesn't* call itself. Instead, the callback function from `$.post()` calls your function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of doing this,

```
if( testlength > 1 )
{
    maxVal++;
    updateAcc();
}
```

you can use

```
if( testlength > 1 )
{
    updateAcc(maxVal+1);
}
```

This way you can call the function with `maxVal` increased by one.

The `maxVal` parameter is "unique" to the `iteration`.